# Currently, no connection to www.gravatar.com

Tags: bug, status-norepro, connectivity

My little gravar-icon in the status-bar and many other icons are no longer present.

I tried to open the gravar-link directly, to no avail.

Pinging www.gravatar.com:

```
PING cs91.wac.edgecastcdn.net (68.232.35.121) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 68.232.35.121: icmp_req=1 ttl=54 time=1535 ms
64 bytes from 68.232.35.121: icmp_req=2 ttl=54 time=2883 ms
```

while pinging stackoverflow.com:

```
PING stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=1425 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=938 ms
64 bytes from stackoverflow.com (198.252.206.140): icmp_req=3 ttl=49 time=893 ms
```

I am : `91.141.2.142.wireless.dyn.drei.com` which is in `.at` connected via a hotspot.

I can `wget` [my gravatar picture](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6faf9276b1eabd5e409a88924180362b?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG). But pasting the same link into FF 27 just waits.

All this I encounter since ~6 hours.

In the past at least ~a week ago, there were never such problems in the same config.

Comment: I can't repro this on IE11 or FF. Do you see errors in the devconsole? In which part of the world are you?

Comment: No such problems here either. Your [gravatar](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6faf9276b1eabd5e409a88924180362b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) loads just fine for me. [downforeveryoneorjustme](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.gravatar.com) also thinks the gravatar server is up and running.

Comment: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/gravatar.com

Comment: @Oded: I can ping it. But I do not get **any** link of it to open in my browser.

Comment: I'm being routed to the same IP. Are you sure your virusscanner or something like that isn't bugging you?

Comment: @rene: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't need virusscanners? :-)

Comment: @rene: I do not know where or not it needs one, but at least there is none.

Comment: Can you use Chrome? Start FF without plugins?

Comment: @rene: I can read with SIII's browser everything. It seems to be specific to FF27 + hotspot etc. Some h's before I was directly connected with FF27 - no problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It probably was some kind of caching problem.

I effectively changed the way of connecting (fixed vs. mobile) while still running the same FF27 - and having open some pages of SO. <s>This caused</s> Then FF did to no longer load some pictures via gravatar.